# getBulkProperties() Hangs and Errors Out

Tags: autodesk-forge

Our application needs to pull a set of properties from all objects in the model. Our application will concatenate properties from leaf nodes with properties from the parent nodes.

We are calling the getBulkProperties() method with around 20K nodes and around 5 properties. This runs for quite some time and then we receive server errors and the callbacks are never invoked.

Is there a limit we should use? Should we split these calls with a max number X of nodes?

Any help would be appreciated as this is causing our application to hang.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a limit, but you may consider listing properties for a specific group at a time, or just leaf nodes.

This [blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/search-method-performance) shows how to optimize the search performance, and the code below ([from this post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/getbulkproperties-method)) how to integrate with **.getBulkProperties**:

```
viewer.search('Steel', 
function(dbIds){
   viewer.model.getBulkProperties(dbIds, ['Mass'],
   function(elements){
     var totalMass = 0;
     for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
       totalMass += elements[i].properties[0].displayValue;
     }
     console.log(totalMass);
   })
}, null, ['Material'])
```

You may also consider enurating only leaf on the model, as shown at [this post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/enumerating-leaf-nodes-viewer) and below:

```
function getAllLeafComponents(viewer, callback) {
    var cbCount = 0; // count pending callbacks
    var components = []; // store the results
    var tree; // the instance tree

    function getLeafComponentsRec(parent) {
        cbCount++;
        if (tree.getChildCount(parent) != 0) {
            tree.enumNodeChildren(parent, function (children) {
                getLeafComponentsRec(children);
            }, false);
        } else {
            components.push(parent);
        }
        if (--cbCount == 0) callback(components);
    }
    viewer.getObjectTree(function (objectTree) {
        tree = objectTree;
        var allLeafComponents = getLeafComponentsRec(tree.getRootId());
    });
}
```